# Enviar dados de um Fragment para uma Activity

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-activity

Bom Dia Pessoal
Tenho um fragment contendo um listview onde listo os dados vindos de um webservice. No método de onclick tenho o seguinte código onde passo alguns valores para uma outra activity de acordo com o código abaixo.

```
ltwPacote.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long 
id) {
JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
String codigo = obj.get("i_cdpacote").getAsString();
String descricaopacote = obj.get("c_descricao").getAsString();
String preco = obj.get("n_precopacote").getAsString();
String regra = obj.get("c_regra").getAsString();
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VisualizaPacote.class);
intent.putExtra("i_cdpacote", codigo);
intent.putExtra("c_descricao", descricaopacote);
intent.putExtra("n_precopacote", preco);
intent.putExtra("c_regra", regra);
startActivity(intent);
```

Na minha activity VisualizaPacote tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String descricao = intent.getStringExtra("descricaopacote");
String preco = intent.getStringExtra("preco");
String regra =intent.getStringExtra("regra");
TextView txtdescricaopacote = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPacote);
txtdescricaopacote.setText(descricao);
TextView txtpreco = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPreco);
txtpreco.setText(preco);
TextView txtregra = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRegra);
txtregra.setText(regra);
```

Acontece que ao clicar sobre o item da lista para visualizar os detalhes esses parâmetros não estão aparecendo na activity de VisualizaPacote.
Se alguém pudesse me orientar, agradeço.

Comment: Tente assim: String descricao = intent.getStringExtra("c_descricao") .....

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo.

Answer (score 2):

Os extras são guardados no intent no formato chave/valor.
Assim, no `intent.getStringExtra()` tem de usar a chave usada no `intent.putExtra()`.

Altere o código da activity assim:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String descricao = intent.getStringExtra("c_descricao");
String preco = intent.getStringExtra("n_precopacote");
String regra =intent.getStringExtra("c_regra");
TextView txtdescricaopacote = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPacote);
txtdescricaopacote.setText(descricao);
TextView txtpreco = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPreco);
txtpreco.setText(preco);
TextView txtregra = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRegra);
txtregra.setText(regra);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Em teoria não é uma boa prática enviar dados de um Fragment direto para outra Activity, pois o princípio do Fragment é ser reutilizável. Por exemplo, se você quisesse implementar um layout multipainel do seu app para tablets, onde seria apenas uma Activity com 2 Fragments, esse seu Fragment não poderia ser reutilizado, pois ele vai abrir outra Activity.

A solução para isso é criar uma interface no seu Fragment para fazer com que a MainActivity​ cuide do clique da ListView e receba os dados necessários do item clicado para decidir o que fazer quando o app estiver rodando em celular (abrir nova Activity passando os dados) ou tablet (passar os dados para o outro Fragment na mesma Activity).

Com relação ao seu problema em específico, é como já responderam, você não está usando a mesma key nos métodos putString e GetStringExtra.