# Parametros entre fragment e activity

Tags: string, google-maps, android-fragment, android-activity, int

Eu tenho uma activity com um fragment dentro, porém quero passar os parametros presente no fragment quando trocar de activity, o que eu faço?

Comment: Olá William, tudo bem? pode explicar melhor e colocar o seu código para que os usuários possam te ajudar da melhor maneira possível?

Comment: o codigo ta gigante, vou tentar explicar melhor. To usando o google maps(que é um fragment), la eu busco a minha localização então eu quero passar essa localização (somente as coordenadas) para um proxima tela, porém não posso colocar um botão direto no fragment do map, so posso colocar na activity e no caso não to conseguindo passar essas informações para a proxima activity, espero que você possa me ajudar.

Comment: Veja uma pergunta parecida. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/200944/enviar-dados-de-um-fragment-para-uma-activity